# Selenium: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to run this script to automate and click on the product list in the webpage using selenium. But this "**raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: error**" is occurring every time. What is wrong I'm doing here? Expecting your guidance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('__headless')

chrome_path = which('chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get('https://www.galaxus.ch/search?q=5010533606001')

product_tab = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//article[@class='panelProduct panelLayout_panelLayout__BDQ6_ view_product__3AOqY']/a"))).click()


time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```

## output

```
    PS G:\Python_Practice\scrapy_practice\test> [21628:13792:0911/125833.339:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(441)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
                                          > & C:/Users/raisu/anaconda3/envs/Scrapy_Workspace2/python.exe g:/Python_Practice/scrapy_practice/test/test.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56456/devtools/browser/1d6d20ce-ecb9-44f7-be6e-1dbe1373526a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:/Python_Practice/scrapy_practice/test/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    product_tab = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//article[@class='panelProduct panelLayout_panelLayout__BDQ6_ view_product__3AOqY']/a"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\raisu\anaconda3\envs\Scrapy_Workspace2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Looks like they are detecting the Selenium as suspicious activity. I tried almost all the possible way in Selenium, couldn't make it work. I think you'd have to induce proxy so that it won't get detected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the xpath, I've used a `CSS_SELECTOR` and also I changed the wait condition for element to be visible

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('__headless')

chrome_path = which('chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get('https://www.galaxus.ch/search?q=5010533606001')

#time.sleep(5)   use this only if the wait is not working
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'article > a')))

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'article > a').click()



driver.close()
```

Comment: PS G:\Python_Practice\scrapy_practice\test> & C:/Users/raisu/anaconda3/envs/Scrapy_Workspace2/python.exe g:/Python_Practice/scrapy_practice/test/test2.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52109/devtools/browser/e022ca0d-9fcd-44a1-95b8-166404088494
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:/Python_Practice/scrapy_practice/test/test2.py", line 21, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'article > a')))
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.support.wait' has no attribute 'until'
PS G:\Python_Practice\scrapy_practice\test>